# Java persistence API when switching to mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using Spring JPA with hibernate as implementation . DB vendor is oracle.

I am doing POC how can migrate existing platform to Mongo DB. Some related questions to that ?

1. Can I continue to use JPA API when switching to Mongo DB?
2. If Yes to point 1, Can I continue to use hibernate and just migrate DB oracle to Mongo DB or is there any better JPA implementation for Mongo DB ?
3. At present hibernate takes care saving objects in their respected tables/relation with proper connection. For example :- user object has 1 to many
   mapping to address object as user can have multiple address. Now once i save user entity, hibernate first save user object in user table. Get userId
   and save it address entity. Now persist address entity in address table

   Similarly in mongoDB , I believe there must be API's which must be doing this stuff(under collection instead of table) out of shelf  where I don't have to do manually like in JDBC era?
4. I know mongoDB does not support ACID properties. But then how will I handle atomicity here ?Say user document is saved but some error occurred while saving address object. How as application developer I can revert the entry under user table also ?

Comment: http://hibernate.org/ogm/ **Hibernate OGM (5.0)
The power and simplicity of JPA for NoSQL datastores**. Including support for associations, sub-classes, queries and much more. The ride has just begun, so come and join us! *I wish to spend sometime to study JPA-NOSQL but not yet* so just this much i as say as of now

Comment: Whenever someone says something like "the ride has just begun, come and join us", I wonder what sort of ride we are talking about.  Will it be like a ride on the back of a wild horse, a tiger ... or a dairy cow?  I think Emily's PM may also be interested in the answer to that.

Comment: Proceed with caution.  You may find that [you need a relational database after all](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/).

Comment: Could you comment on your motivation for considering moving from Oracle / RDBMS to MongoDB? Generally, your data model needs to be rethought when making this change, as, in addition losing some transactional functionality, RDBMS normailzation/denormalization strategies and referential integrity constraints are thrown out the window.